# Connecting two Apple Cinema Displays to Mac Pro (early 2008)

Tags: mac, display, mac-pro

I recently revived my early 2008 Mac Pro 3.1, along with my 30" Cinema Display and my 22" Cinema Display.

When both monitors are connected to their respective female DVI ports on the Mac Pro, only one monitor is recognized.

I switched the plugs around and whichever monitor is plugged into the rightmost port works, while the other remains black and unrecognized.

Why is this? Is there an adapter I need in order for both to work?

Comment: Did you check both cables as well as both monitors? Also, what GPU do you have in it? Original or aftermarket/newer Apple?

Comment: Checked both cables and both monitors, and it all works. GPU is the original one, havent changed anything on the inside. Thanks!

Comment: So that would be an 8800? I don't have a surviving Nvidia I could test against, i'm afraid - all the Pros here have uprated GPUs... nor, actually do we have any surviving Cinemas :\ Give it a couple of days on here & see if anyone comes up with an answer or decent test method. if no joy, flag your question for a moderator to migrate to [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) in case it might get more traction on there. Wish you luck :)